# How to Switch Caps lock between Multiple Documents using swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, capslock

I have wrote code for caps lock.when it enable it ON on statusbar and when it is disable it shows OFF on status bar.Here problem is when I open more than one Document then enable caps lock in Doc1,In this case Doc2 is not enabled.I want to show enable/disable all opened Documents.
In this I have wrote two classes.
Main class:

```
public class OpenDemNew extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ChangeListener{
private ArrayList<OInternalFrame> frames = new ArrayList<OInternalFrame>();
private OInternalFrame currentFrame;
int i=0;
public OpenDemNew() {
initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                         
private void initComponents() {

tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jMenu1.setText("File");
open.setText("Open");
open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        openActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
jMenu1.add(open);
jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);

pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
 private void openActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(OpenDemNew.this, "Select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.setVisible(true);
String title;
String sts;

if (fd.getFile() != null) {
   sts = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
   title=fd.getFile();
   System.out.println(sts);
   title=fd.getFile();
   BufferedReader br = null;
   StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
   try {
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sts));
       String line;
       try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line + "\n");
            }
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OpenDemNew.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OpenDemNew.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
   String t = str.toString(); 
   OInternalFrame internalFrame = new OInternalFrame("",true,true);  
   i++;
   internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
   internalFrame.setTitle(title);
   try {
        internalFrame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OpenDemNew.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
   tp.add(internalFrame);
   tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  
   tp.addChangeListener(this);
   frames.add(internalFrame);
   currentFrame=internalFrame;
   currentFrame.setText(t);
   currentFrame.setVisible(true);

}     
}                                    

public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info :     javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemNew.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemNew.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemNew.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(OpenDemNew.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
//</editor-fold>
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new OpenDemNew().setVisible(true);
    }
});
}                   
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem open;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;                  

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) ce.getSource();
int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
try
{
  currentFrame =frames.get(index);
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e1){
}
```

}
}

And another program is OInternalFrame.OinternalFrame is having the status bar and caps lock logic.
Code is:

```
public class OInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame
{
private JTextArea textPane;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
JPanel statusbarPanel;
JLabel statusLabel;
JLabel capsLabel;
private DocumentListener listen;
public OInternalFrame(String title,boolean resizable,boolean closable)
{
    super(title,resizable,closable);
    initComponents();
    initListeners();
}
private void initComponents()
{

    textPane = new JTextArea();
    statusbarPanel=new JPanel();
    statusLabel=new JLabel();
    capsLabel=new JLabel();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    textPane.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
    add(scrollPane);
    statusbarPanel.add(statusLabel);
    statusbarPanel.add(capsLabel);
    add(statusbarPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(textPane); 
    setVisible(true);
    updateStatus(1,1);
    if(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)){
        capsLabel.setText("ON");
    }
    else {
         capsLabel.setText("OFF");
    }
    scrollPane.setVisible(true);

}
private void initListeners()
{
    textPane.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {

            int linenum = 1;
            int columnnum = 1;
            try {
                linenum=getLineAtCaret()-1;
                columnnum=getColumnAtCaret();
                linenum += 1;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { }
            updateStatus(linenum, columnnum);
        }
    });
    textPane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)){
                   capsLabel.setText("ON");
            }
            else{
                    capsLabel.setText("OFF");
            }

        }
    });
     }
public void setText(String t)
{
    textPane.setText(t);
    textPane.setCaretPosition(0);
    textPane.setVisible(true);
    textPane.repaint();
}

public int getLineAtCaret()
{   
    int line = 0;
    int caretPosition = textPane.getCaretPosition();
    try {
        line = textPane.getLineOfOffset(caretPosition);

    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return line+1;
}

public int getColumnAtCaret()
{
    FontMetrics fm = textPane.getFontMetrics( textPane.getFont() );
    int characterWidth = fm.stringWidth( "0" );
    int column = 0;
    try
    {
        Rectangle r = textPane.modelToView( textPane.getCaretPosition() );
        int width = r.x - textPane.getInsets().left;
        column = width / characterWidth;
    }
    catch(BadLocationException ble) {}
    return column + 1;
}

private void updateStatus(int linenumber, int columnnumber) 
{
    statusLabel.setText("Line: " + linenumber + " Column: " + columnnumber);
}
```

}

Comment: keypressed or keyReleased is called only when you press the key when Window/JFrame is in focus.

Comment: JTtextPane isn't designated to by used, listened by KeyListener, don't to use KeyListener for Swing JComponents

Comment: [there are prerequisities for LockingKeyState](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22787592/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel Okay,for this Problem,what can I use to solve this.

Comment: @user3556256 not sure about whats - `Okay,for this Problem,what can I use to solve this.` -  if is about KeyListener then to use Document(model for JTextComponents, there you have to convert view to model) and DocumentListener or DocumentFilter (for changes to its own Document)

Comment: I would say it's not usual to have status and toolbar for each frame. Normally there is juts one toolbar and status bar for the whole app which reflected selected frame state.

Comment: @StanislavL How can I modify my application code wise.

Comment: Move the components from OInternalFrame to the main frame. Listen Internal frames activating and refresh the toolbar/statusbar accordingly with data from new active frame.

Comment: @stanislavL In earlier days my application has wrote in single class.At that the problem is Menu Items are not working for all Documents,work for recently opened Document.That's why I split this class into two.If I club both in one class then again issue is repeated.If possible change my code to single class that works for all Documents.