# Java - GetLockingState() won't update

Tags: java, keyboard, awt

Found bug [Java Bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4414164)

"CAPS" doesn't update. I want it to be actively checking the locking state but it only checks it once and stores true/false in "CAPS" but if you hit caps lock it doesn't change the boolean stored in CAPS.

```
Thread capsCheck = new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        boolean CAPS = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);

        if (CAPS) {
            System.out.println("Caps enabled");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Caps disabled");
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, it works fine for me.

Comment: I reproduced this on `windows10 ` with `jre-10.0.2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(...) never updates during program exectution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786282/toolkit-getdefaulttoolkit-getlockingkeystate-never-updates-during-program)