# Caps lock detection returns false value after refocus

Tags: java, swing

I have JFrame that has to detect whether the caps lock is on or off. If I am focusing the Window everything works fine, the programm detects the change of the caps lock status through a KeyListener. While the window is minimized, I can't check the caps lock status, so I check the status after the user re-focuses the window. But then the check returns the last Caps lock status I got instead of the current one.

```
JFrame frame;

public example() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Caps Lock Status: " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK));
        }

        @Override
        public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            // nothing to do
        }
    });

}
```

If my caps lock was off while the window was openend and I am turning the caps lock on while the window was unfocused. Then I expect a true from the programm after the window was refocused.

I appreciate all kinds of suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Could you please let us know what is your OS, and what is your Java Version?

Comment: Seems like a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021847/java-getlockingstate-wont-update

Comment: @GeorgeZ. I can produce this behaviour on Windows 7/10 and my Java Version is 8.

Comment: @camickr I can´t reproduce the descriped behaviour in your attached question. If the window is focused everything works just fine, the detection and behaviour is great. If I change the caps lock status, while the window is not focused, the check will return the last caps lock status, before the window was unfocused.

Comment: Can I ask why do you need to detect when CAPS LOCK is on? I mean maybe there is another way to do what you want...

Comment: @GeorgeZ. So the idea is, that if an user wants to sign-In, the application shows him that his Caps-Lock is On/Off, to prevent false inputs (Like on Windows 10). To cover any cases, I need to check if the user switched the Caps-Lock while the application was minimized.

Answer (score 1):

As @camickr pointed out correctly in the comment section, it has to do with a bug. Probably with the Windows toolkit. I tried few things in order to make this work and the only stable (tested about 100 times) is to press/unpress CAPS LOCK 2 times (one to change its state and one to bring it back) with some `sleep` time between and then ask the value from the toolkit. In order to achieve that (sleep the thread), we will need to use a `SwingWorker`. I have a created a `SwingWorker` class that takes a `Consumer<Boolean>` argument and accepts it when its finished. The `Boolean` value in the consumer represents if the caps lock is on/off.

Take a look:

```
public class CapsLockDetectWorker extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> {
    private Consumer<Boolean> consumer;
    private static final int CAPS_LOCK = KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK;

    public CapsLockDetectWorker(Consumer<Boolean> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(CAPS_LOCK);
        robot.keyRelease(CAPS_LOCK);
        Thread.sleep(3);
        robot.keyPress(CAPS_LOCK);
        robot.keyRelease(CAPS_LOCK);
        Thread.sleep(3);
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(CAPS_LOCK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            Boolean isCapsOn = get();
            consumer.accept(isCapsOn);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And an example of how to you use it:

```
public class CapsLockDetection {
    private JFrame frame;

    public CapsLockDetection() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                new CapsLockDetectWorker(b -> {
                    System.out.println("ENABLED CAPS LOCK:" + b);
                }).execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                // nothing to do
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new CapsLockDetection();
        });
    }
}
```

Of course, if your computer has a `caps lock` button with a light (or there is one in your keyboard somewhere), you are going to see it blinking (turn off/on)...

I know it looks silly, but I do not think you will find something better.